# How to determine which service is behind an Azure Public IP?

Tags: azure, azure-public-ip

Is there any chance to determine which service is behind an Azure Public IP.

I know that there is a list of [Microsoft Azure Datacenter IP Ranges](http://Microsoft%20Azure%20Datacenter%20IP%20Ranges) where you can see in which location the Public IP is. I already checked it and was able to determine. But what I want to check is, which service is behind that - is there any chance?

Answer (score 0):

I heard that some services publish their specific IP ranges, but for the most part the answer is "no".